# Split a string then check it

Tags: python

I need some code that will split password into multiple strings where there is a space and that i can then check if that is a a word in wordnet, does anyone know how to do this.

```
checker = str.split(password)
if wordnet.synsets(checker):
    print("your password is: "+ password)
    nextcheck = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example

```
password = "This is a password"

# split the input string
split_password = password.split()

# iterate through the words in split_password
for word in split_password:
    # get the sysnet list for each word
    sysnet_list = wordnet.synsets(word)
    # here you can do whatever you need with every element of the list
    # so print it if you like
    if sysnet_list:
        for potential_password in sysnet_list:
            print(f"Your password is {potential_password}")
    else:
         print(f"No potential password found for {word}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
password = 'Hello there'

checker = password.split(' ')
print(checker)
```

This returns a list with the individual words. You can then loop through that list and check each word.